# Extract distinct and count without using filter option

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have given column something like this

```
| list |
|------|
| A    |
| B    |
| A    |
| A    |
| B    |
```

And I want to create new column which include unique/distinct value from above column and shows count of each occuring. I can do this using filter option and count. But I am looking for any formula to perform this.

Required Output:

```
| Unique | Count |
|--------|-------|
| A      | 3     |
| B      | 2     |
```

Thank you for time and consideration.

Comment: Use pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

As Akina said, pivot would be the easiest way, but if you want to do it with formulas, here are a couple:

for distinct list:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$7)=0),$A$2:$A$7),"")
```

for count:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,D2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365, use the UNIQUE() function (plus SORT() if you want a sorted list):

`=SORT(UNIQUE(A2:A6))`

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tohMW.png)